# Infimum problem lemma to prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am seeing this infimum problem which is serving as a helper proof to prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular, and having difficulty finding a way to use the infimum property.

Problem:Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology. Let $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a point not in a closed set $A$. Show that $\text{inf}\{d(a,p)|a \in A\}>0$.

Attempt$(1)$:Assume $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is not in $A$, but $d(a,p)=0$. Then $a=p$ and $a \in A$ contradiction to $p \notin A$.So each $d(a,p)>0$ for each $p \in \mathbb{R}^2-A$. Now I am having difficulty seeing the contradiction if the infimum is potentially $0$. So I do not think this proof is sufficient.And I am nowhere using the infimum property anywhere.

Attempt$(2)$:Assume $\text{inf}\{d(a,p)|a \in A\}=0$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$, $\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $\text{inf}\{d(a,p)|a \in A\}$.So there's a sequence $\{\epsilon_i\}$ of small numbers with $\epsilon>\epsilon_2>\dots$ converging to $0$ and $\{p_i\}$ not in $A$ with $d(a,p_i)<\epsilon_i$. Then $a=\text{lim}p_i$ and so $\{p_{i}\}$ is sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2-A$ converging to $a \in A$. Again I am stuck.

How should I approach this problem differently?

Comment: If $\inf\{d(a,p) : a\in A\} = 0$, then there exists a sequence $(a_n)\subset A$ such that $d(a_n,p)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Prove: $(a_n)$ converges. What is the limit? Since $A$ is closed and each $a_n$ is in $A$, so is the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use that $p \in \overline{A}$ iff for every ball $B(p,r)$ with $r>0$ we have that $B(p,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. This holds in any metric space, not just $\Bbb R^2$.

It follows that if $p \notin A$ where $A$ is closed, we have some $r>0$ so that $B(p,r) \cap A = \emptyset$.