# Prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular. I got stuck on this proof even though the answer was almost given to me [Infimum problem lemma to prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042726/infimum-problem-lemma-to-prove-mathbbr2-is-regular).

Let $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $p \notin A$, where $A$ is closed. Then there is some $r>0$ with $B_r(p) \cap A =\varnothing.$ Now I know I need to find an open set containing $A$ disjoint from $B_r(p)$, and this was my issue. I just guessed to take for each $a \in A$, $U_a=\text{inf}\{d(a,p)|a \in A\}$, the infimum of this set. Then would $\cup_{a \in A}U_a$ be an open set containing $A$ disjoint from $B_r(p)$? Now I realize my answer does not make sense without defining the open set containing $A$ dependent on $r$, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to let $s\in(0,r)$ and use the open sets $B_s(p)$ and $\Bbb R^2\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_s(p)$: $\operatorname{cl}B_s(p)\subseteq B_r(p)$, so $\Bbb R^2\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_s(p)\supseteq\Bbb R\setminus B_r(p)\supseteq A$.

Your definition of $U_a$ makes it the infimum of a set of non-negative real numbers, so it is simply a real number, not a subset of $\Bbb R$. I suspect that you wanted to do something like this: let $s=\inf\{d(a,p):a\in A\}$, and consider $\bigcup_{a\in A}B_s(a)$. That gives you an open nbhd of $A$ that does not contain $p$, but it does not give you one that is disjoint from $B_r(p)$. You could, however, let $s=\frac{r}2$ and set $U=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_s(a)$; then it’s an easy exercise in the triangle inequality to show that $B_s(p)\cap U=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p \notin A$ and $A$ is closed, then note that $A^\complement$ is open and $p$ is in it, so by definition there is some $r>0$ such that $B(p,r) \subseteq A^\complement$.

Now $U = B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ and $V = \bigcup \{B(a, \frac{r}{2})\mid a \in A\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $A$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$: if $q \in U \cap V$ then $q \in B(p, \frac{r}{2})$ and for some $a_0 \in A$, $q \in B(a_0, \frac{r}{2})$. But then $d(p, a_0) \le d(p,q) + d(q, a_0) < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2}= r$ so that $a_0 \in B(p,r)$, contradicting $B(p,r) \subseteq A^\complement$.

To show normality is similar.